# Meaning difference between Wandering and Roaming

Tags: difference

What is the difference between the words "Wandering" and "Roaming"? 
Don't both of them mean *an aimless movement*?

In Wordweb dictionary their meanings are described as:

Wandering: Travelling without any clear destination  and
Roaming: Move aimlessly without any destination.

So, is there any specific difference between the two?

Comment: I don't like that definition of roaming.  I believe one can roam with a purpose.  For example a polar bear may need to roam to find food- so there can be a purpose to roaming.  Try [this definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roam): *to travel purposefully unhindered through a wide area*

Comment: @Jim I think the original definition is missing an *or*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, *to wander* and *to roam* are synonyms, and they both can mean *to move about aimlessly or without any destination, often in search of food or employment.*

However, *to wander* has some additional meanings that *to roam* doesn't:

- Lose clarity or turn aside from the main subject. (Her mind wanders.)
- To be sexually unfaithful.
- To go an indirect route or at no set pace. (We wandered into town.)
- To move in a sinuous, spiral or circular course. (Synonym with meander.)

Comment: And *to roam* has some additional meanings that *to wander* doesn't

Answer (score 0):

To me, *roam* has a flavor of being unintentional about location but not necessarily unintentional about purpose. It's also more frequently used to describe the movements and activities of animals.

Roaming animals are very busy and intent on their animal priorities, but they don't necessarily care where they are doing them. So to me, roaming can include things like looking for food, sex, seasonal migration or satisfying curiosity. But I wouldn't get those kinds of flavoring from *wander*.

On the other hand, *wander* implies moving without intensity of purpose either in direction or activity.

*Wander* often implies slow speed, but not always. Whereas for me, *roam* would imply the typical speed of an animal grazing or hunting depending on the habits of their particular species. Roaming buffalo and roaming tigers don't imply the same speeds at all to me.

ghoppe pointed out some additional meanings of wander. Some additional meanings of roam includes moving outside of your normal cellular phone network. However, unlike ghoppe I think roam can also mean "to be sexually unfaithful."

Both wander and roam can be used to imply movement outside of expected or accepted boundaries or paths, but neither has to mean that, and that kind of meaning depends on context. In those contexts they are synonymous with the verb *stray*.

For example, unwelcome grouping could be identified as wandering or roaming or straying hands.